# Create an array of rgb images in mat format?

Tags: image, matlab

I am having 60 images of size 250x250x3 . Now I want to add it as a stack of images.
ie, I want to create a 4-D array, which holds all the images in the form of a mat file. So, it should be of size 250 x 250 x 3 x 60 .

I have tried the following. But when I displays the image it is full of white with some small marks only. This was the code .

```
X=zeros(250,250,3,60)
for i=1:60
X(:,:,:,i)=image1 and so on on every every loop.
```

Any way to create this mat.

Answer (score 1):

#### The problem:

It seems like yout images are stored as `uint8` type. When you pre-allocated your `X` you defined it as `double` (by default).
When Matlab displays an image there is a difference between a `uint8` type image and `double` type image: for `uint8` Matlab expects the intensities to range between [0..255]. However, when it comes to `double` type images Matlab expects the values to range between [0..1]. Thus, assigning `uint8` image values to `double` type you have a double type image with values in the range [0..255] - which Matlab displays as white.

#### Solutions:

There are several ways you can solve your problem:

- Define `X` as a `uint8` type

  X = zeros( [255, 255, 3, 60], 'uint8' )
  This will save memory as `uint8` takes single byte whereas `double` takes 8.
- Alternatively, you can cast your images to `double` using `im2double` function that changes the data type **and** the range of intensities to [0..1].